# The good way to Update model with context EF Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

What is a good way of updating the model via context EF core?

I have function like this:

```
public class ApplicationContext : DbContext { }

public class Repository<T>
{
   private readonly ApplicationContext context;
   public Repository(ApplicationContext context)
   {
      this.context = context;
   }

   public void Update(T entity)
   {
      context.Update(entity);
   }

   public async Task SaveAsync()
   {
      await context.SaveChangesAsync();
   }
}
```

Function in service will call repository like this when it wants to update some model.

```
public void SomeFunction()
{
   var model = repository.GetData();
   model.Variable = "changed";
   repository.Update(model);
   await repository.SaveAsync();
}
```

Is there any good way to update my model? Also, I want to change my `Update` function like this:

```
public void Update(T entity)
{
   EntityEntry<T> entity = context.Entry(item);
   entity.State = EntityState.Modified;
}
```

Is this already good?

thanks before

Comment: If you want to review your code, go to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: If you don't use the Repository pattern with EF then your updates are very straight forward.